# Bootstrap 4 - How do I right-align a dropdown list in a navbar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web page built with Bootstrap 4. In my page, I have a navbar. That navbar has a settings icon that the user can click. The setting icon is right-aligned in the navbar. When clicked, the settings form appears.

As shown in this [Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/tk9AhUWJOx), the setting form appears. However, the form is not right-aligned with the button. Instead, the settings from seems to hover from left-to-right. In addition, the content of the settings from is not evenly distributed into two columns like I'd expect. What am I doing wrong? My code looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark" style="background-color:orange;">
    <div class="row" style="width:100%;">
      <div class="col-10 offset-1">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">
            <h3 class="mb-0"><small class="text-muted">Dashboard</small></h3>
          </div>

          <div class="col-6 d-flex align-items-end">
            <ul class="list-inline navbar-nav d-inline ml-auto">
              <li class="list-inline-item nav-item dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle py-0 mb-0 float-right" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" style="position:relative; top:4px; right:-16px;" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                  <i class="text-muted">cog</i>
                </button>

                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" style="position:absolute;">
                        <form class="p-3">
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                 <label for="filterLocation">Location</label>
                                 <select class="form-control" id="form-control">
                                    <option>Chicago</option>
                                    <option>New York</option>
                                </select>
                              </div>                                                            
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="filterTo">Via Date</label>                                  
                                    <input class="form-control mb-2 mb-sm-0" id="filterFromDate" type="text" placeholder="11.01.2017">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </form>

                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>              
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use this :

```
 <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right float-right" style="position:absolute;">
```

instead of this :

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" style="position:absolute;">
```

"float-right" css class is the old "pull-right" class but they changed it in bootstrap 4 and by the way your Bootply doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" style="position:absolute; margin-left: 15px">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code. It will clear the column problem.

Adding `min-width:300px;` can make it work.

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark" style="background-color:orange;">
    <div class="row" style="width:100%;">
      <div class="col-10 offset-1">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">
            <h3 class="mb-0"><small class="text-muted">Dashboard</small></h3>
          </div>

          <div class="col-6 d-flex align-items-end">
            <ul class="list-inline navbar-nav d-inline ml-auto">
              <li class="list-inline-item nav-item dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle py-0 mb-0 float-right" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" style="position:relative; top:4px; right:-16px;" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                  <i class="text-muted">cog</i>
                </button>

                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" style="position:absolute;min-width:300px;">
                        <form class="p-3">
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                 <label for="filterLocation">Location</label>
                                 <select class="form-control" id="form-control">
                                    <option>Chicago</option>
                                    <option>New York</option>
                                </select>
                              </div>                                                            
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="filterTo">Via Date</label>                                  
                                    <input class="form-control mb-12 mb-sm-0" id="filterFromDate" type="text" placeholder="11.01.2017">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </form>

                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>              
  </nav>
</div>
```